# How to connect sftp using mule requestor in mule 3.9

Tags: mule, sftp, mulesoft, mule-component

**How to connect SFTP using mule requestor in mule 3.9?
How to create a source path**

Wanted to know hoe to connect to sftp using mule requester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to configure the resource attribute as the [URL for an SFTP endpoint](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-endpoint-uris):

```
<mulerequester:request resource="sftp://${USER_NAME}:${PASSWORD}@${SFTP_HOST}:${SFTP_PORT}/path/to/file" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
```

All values in the URL need to be URL encoded. This is usually only a problem for passwords that have special characters in it.

Alternative you can define a global SFTP [endpoint](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/endpoint-configuration-reference) and reference it in the resource attribute by name.

In Mule 4 the Mule Requester Module is not supported and not needed because most Mule 4 connectors provide equivalent operations to use inside flows in a supported way.